# Sonata admin display string matching integer values

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'm using sonata admin for my backoffice application.
My entity has an integer field, each value has a meaning that I'd like to display in words.
For instance, say that it has the opinion field, which can be 0, 1, 2 or 3.
0 means no opinion
1 means I agree
2 means I don't agree
3 means I've got to explain

In my db I store 0, 1, 2 or 3 and on the CRUD interfaces I need to display the string values

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it , this is one approach

In your entity define constants like so :

```
Class EntityName
{
    const NO_OPINION = 0;
    const I_AGREE = 1;
    const I_DONT_AGREE = 2;
    const I_GOTTA_EXPLAIN = 3;

   // field which holds those values
   protected $status = EntityName::NO_OPINION;


//
```

In the admin class

```
$listMapper
    ->addIdentifier('id')
    ->add('status', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array(
    EntityName::NO_OPINION => "No Opinion",
    EntityName::I_AGREE => 'I Agree',
    EntityName::I_DONT_AGREE => 'I Don\'t Agree',
    EntityName::I_GOTTA_EXPLAIN => 'I\'ve got to explain', 
    )
    ))
    ->add('somethingelse')
```

Comment: Works fine! What about the code option in https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/action_list.html#options

Comment: @smarber : try it out and let me know